# Django restframework, extra_kwargs not working

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model. I have created an api for user registration. Following is my serializer.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())
        ]
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}, }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        email = validated_data.pop('email')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(email, password, **validated_data)
        return user
```

Here is my view:

```
class Registration(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

There are two inputs `email` and `password`. `password` field is given as write_only field. But after creating the user, the api returns the hashed password. How can I prevent the password being returned?

[image]

Comment: What about using `django-rest-registration`  https://github.com/szopu/django-rest-registration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need explicitly declare the field on the serializer if use `extra_kwargs` try just this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())
        ]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 8}}
```

Comment: It helped a lot. Thanks!